# html &nbsp has symbol on spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a paragraph tag in between two buttons with spacing. The small issue is the weird symbol when I add the " " command. I just need to take it out, or I'd like to know if there is an alternate way in adding space.

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-md-12 text-align-center">
  <button type="submit" href="../cards" class="fb_btn registerbtn">LOGIN</button>
  <span class="color-gray small">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  <button type="submit" href="cards/register.php" class="fb_btn registerbtn">REGISTER</button>
  <p>to claim this coupon</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use margins?  The way you're using `&nbsp;` is not really what it's intended purpose is...

Comment: Give the span a `margin:0 10px 0 10px`

Comment: I'm getting curious. Can you point to a website where this happens? Or if you can't, what font are you using?

Comment: I mean, I know the solution is easy - don't use `&nbsp;`. But the problem is that those spaces are not supposed to look like that - they're supposed to look like spaces! - and this solution only sweeps the problem under the mat. What if you need to use a `&nbsp;` elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to use padding (left & right) instead of space(`&nbsp;`). Check out the preview at https://jsfiddle.net/jwe8h49z/9/

Answer (score 0):

Apply CSS Box Modeling and apply margin or padding instead of using &nbsp

```html
<style>
button{
 margin: 10px;
}
</style>

<div class="col-md-12 text-align-center">
  <button type="submit" href="../cards" class="fb_btn registerbtn">LOGIN</button>
  <span class="color-gray small">or</span>
  <button type="submit" href="cards/register.php" class="fb_btn registerbtn">REGISTER</button>
  <p>to claim this coupon</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any grey marks with just your code and boostrap [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aQdPrP). Seems like something else is going on?

Also, as @Erik Philips suggested, a better way would be to use margins.

Here's an example:

```html
<div class="col-md-12 text-align-center" >
    <button type="submit" href="../cards" class="fb_btn registerbtn" style="margin-right: 10px;">LOGIN</button>
    <span class="color-gray small">or</span>
    <button type="submit" href="cards/register.php" class="fb_btn registerbtn" style="margin-left: 10px;">REGISTER</button>
    <p>to claim this coupon</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fb_btn{
  padding:5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 text-align-center">
  <button type="submit" href="../cards" class="fb_btn registerbtn">LOGIN</button>
  <span class="color-gray small">or</span>
  <button type="submit" href="cards/register.php" class="fb_btn registerbtn">REGISTER</button>
  <p>to claim this coupon</p>
</div>
```

Use `CSS` to add spaces between controls.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you --

```css
button{background:#f2901a; color:#fff; border:0; padding:15px; width:120px;}
.color-gray{padding:0 20px; position:relative; }
.color-gray::before{content:'---'; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;}
.color-gray::after{content:'---'; position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px;}
.text-align-center{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 text-align-center">
  <button type="submit" href="../cards" class="fb_btn registerbtn">LOGIN</button>
  <span class="color-gray small">or</span>
  <button type="submit" href="cards/register.php" class="fb_btn registerbtn">REGISTER</button>
  <p>to claim this coupon</p>
</div>
```